# How to write two install .iso (for example windows and linux) on one flash?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, live-usb, usb-drive, iso

How to write two installer .iso images (for example Windows and a Linux system like Ubuntu) on one USB flash drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)** (Your Universal Multiboot Installer). Its a great utility to list down multiple ISO files in one boot menu.