# Is it possible to install two ISO on single USB using only DD?

Tags: usb, iso, dd

I have a 16 GB Pendrive and I would like to put Windows 11 ISO and Ubuntu 22.04 ISO and make it bootable. I would like to pick the ISO to launch every time the USB is inserted.

I saw that there are some programs that do that:

- [How to write two install .iso (for example windows and linux) on one flash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345769/how-to-write-two-install-iso-for-example-windows-and-linux-on-one-flash)
- [How to create a bootable USB with multiple ISO images in it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46624/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-with-multiple-iso-images-in-it)

But they use an external program to do that. **I would like to do that with "dd" tool**, for example as they do in this thread: [How to burn a Windows .iso to a USB device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59551/how-to-burn-a-windows-iso-to-a-usb-device)

using the command `sudo dd bs=4M if=[your.iso] of=/dev/sd[X]`

Is that possible? Maybe I should create 2 partition on the USB, one for Windows one for Linux, but the how can I pick which one to launch?

**EDIT**: If there is another way to do that without DD but that does not require to install an external program, I would be glad to hear

Comment: Use ventoy.https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html " I would like to do that with "dd" tool, " sure... but .... " but the how can I pick which one to launch?" you can't so no. Use ventoy.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I edited the post. Isn't there another way to "pick which one to launch" without using an External program? For example, could I install grub on the USB so it lets me pick the ISO to launch?

Edit, I saw that [I can install grub on the usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180023/can-i-install-grub-on-an-usb-and-make-it-a-rescue-disk) using the command `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb` will this let me pick the ISO to load?

Comment: You can install grub to flash drive, but have to manually create a grub boot stanza. And that can use loopmount to just mount & boot the ISO directly. I now prefer SSD with full install that already has grub, so I just add boot stanzas to 40_custom. https://www.supergrubdisk.org/wiki/Loopback.cfg & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot & https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Multiboot_USB_drive#GParted_Live

Comment: Yes, you can create partitions on a thumb-drive, and thus `dd` to write anything you like (including ISOs) to partitions, allowing many to co-exist.  This will confuse most boot loaders (*firmware of boxes that start the boot process*), but you can *jimmy* up using `grub` something to select which you'll use.  I"ve done it myself, alas not recently.

Comment: Probably good old grub4dos is the way to go since Windows involved...